# Adding modifies to a method breaks loop invariant

Tags: dafny

The overarching problem is that when I add modifies to a method, suddenly some of my loop invariants no longer check correctly.

I have worked around this by extracting that loop out into its own method, however that feels very hacky.

```
method Merge (arr : array<int>, l : int, m : int, r : int) returns (res : array<int>)
    requires 0 <= l < m < r <= arr.Length
    requires sorted_slice(arr, l, m);
    requires sorted_slice(arr, m, r);
    ensures sorted_slice(res, l, r)
{
    var ia := l;
    var ib := m;
    res := new int[r - l];
    var ri := 0;
    while ri < res.Length
        decreases res.Length - ri
        invariant ri == (ia - l) + (ib - m)
        
        //Ensure that the ia/ib is within the sorted slice at all times
        invariant l <= ia <= m
        invariant m <= ib <= r

        // r[:ri] is sorted
        invariant forall j, k :: (0 <= j <= k < ri) && (0 <= j <= k < res.Length) ==> res[j] <= res[k]
        invariant forall ja, jr :: (ia <= ja < m) && (0 <= jr < ri < res.Length) ==> res[jr] <= arr[ja]
        invariant forall jb, jr :: (ib <= jb < r) && (0 <= jr < ri < res.Length) ==> res[jr] <= arr[jb]
    {
        if ia >= m {
            res[ri] := arr[ib];
            ib := ib + 1;
            ri := ri + 1;
        } else if ib >= r {
            res[ri] := arr[ia];
            ia := ia + 1;
            ri := ri + 1;
        } else {
            if arr[ia] < arr[ib]
            {
                res[ri] := arr[ia];
                ia := ia + 1;
                ri := ri + 1;
            } else {
                res[ri] := arr[ib];
                ib := ib + 1;
                ri := ri + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Specifically the 4th and 5th loop invariants fail when I add `modifies arr` to `Merge`'s signature.

Why might this be occurring? I can understand that I might need to add an invariant to the loop saying that it doesn't edit `arr`, however I can't find how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loop inherits any `modifies` clause of the enclosing method [0]. So, if your method says `modifies arr`, then, in effect, so does your loop. This means that the verifier will treat the loop as if it may modify the elements of `arr`, whether or not the loop body actually does [1]. Therefore, you are indeed correct that you need to add something to the loop specification that says that the loop doesn't actually modify `arr`.

Your method is also allowed to modify the elements of `res`, because array `res` is "newly allocated" inside the method. This means that your loop is allowed to modify both `arr` and `res`, if your method says `modifies arr`.

So, you want to override the inherited `modifies` clause, so that you can restrict the effective `modifies` clause for the loop to be only `res`. To do that, write

```
modifies res
```

among the `decreases` and `invariant` clauses on the loop.

Fine points, just for reference:

- [0] For a nested loop, the inner loop inherits the effective `modifies` clause of the enclosing loop.
- [1] If the verifier can determine by a simple syntactic scan that the loop body couldn't possibly modify anything in the heap, then the verifier uses this fact, regardless of `modifies` clauses.
- Btw, for your program, you can omit the explicit `decreases` clause, because Dafny will infer it for you.